# how protocols are being chosen?

Tags: http, server

so I have made server which sends a picture to client. but when snaffing the packets I see that the protocol of the packet is HTTP. why would it be HTTP but no other?

```
import socket

file_to_return = open(r"C:\Users\hadad\Desktop\webroot\imgs\abstract.jpg", 'rb')
file_content = file_to_return.read()

server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(("0.0.0.0", 80))
server_socket.listen()
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
client_socket.send(file_content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Port 80 is conventionally the port for an HTTP service. But nothing stops someone from ignoring the conventions and running a completely different service / protocol on port 80.

Of course, people who do that kind of thing are liable to cause trouble for themselves and annoyance for other people.

The standard port # to protocol mappings are defined by IANA:

- [Service Name and Transport Protocol Port Number Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml)

On a typical Linux / UNIX system, the standard port assignments are also listed in the `/etc/services` file.

---

> Why would it be HTTP but no other?

Because *sensible* people follow the conventions.

Comment: so every time I use this port the protocol will be HTTP by default?

Comment: Unless you connect to a service that has been set up by someone who is perversely flouting the conventions!  (I've never seen someone do that deliberately ... but it is a big internet out there, and there some crazy people.)

Comment: ok thank you very much! I will not be one of them